# Can't connect with remote user to MySQL (hosted on Ubuntu VPS)

Tags: mysql, ssh, remote-access, ubuntu-server, navicat

I am trying to setup a remote user for my MySQL db so I can access it from any IP. 
The MySQL server is hosted on a Ubuntu VPS server.

I already created a remote user as you can see here:

```
login as: root
root@xx.xx.xx's password:
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-108-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  Get cloud support with Ubuntu Advantage Cloud Guest:
    http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/cloud

82 packages can be updated.
42 updates are security updates.


Last login: Fri Mar  2 19:47:15 2018 from xxxxxxx
root@vpsxxxxxx:~# mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 10
Server version: 5.7.21-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input     statement.

mysql> SHOW variables WHERE Variable_name = 'hostname' OR Variable_name =     'port';
+---------------+-----------+
| Variable_name | Value     |
+---------------+-----------+
| hostname      | vps520749 |
| port          | 3306      |
+---------------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT Host,User from mysql.user;
+-----------+------------------+
| Host      | User             |
+-----------+------------------+
| %         | user             |
| localhost | debian-sys-maint |
| localhost | mysql.session    |
| localhost | mysql.sys        |
| localhost | root             |
+-----------+------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

But once I try to login with the user `user` via Navicat or MySQL Workbench I get this error:

[image: Error message in Navicat]

Even if I try to connect to the SQL server over SSH I still get an error:

[image: Error in MySQL Workbench using SSH]

Btw here my settings for the connection:

[image: Navi get connection settings]

[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have a possible problem with remote privileges. If that is the case, open MySQL on the command line and enter this in:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES
ON my_database_name.*
TO 'user'@'%'
IDENTIFIED BY 'new_remote_password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

'%' is a wildcard, so the `TO` line says that a username 'user' with any IP address has access. But they'll need the password `new_remote_password`. And as you can see, the `ON` line limits this access to one database, my_database_name.

And there are some obvious security risks by doing this, so make sure you know what you are doing in that regard.

Here are some other possible fixes:

Change a line or two in the config file. Typically the config file is at `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` or `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` on Ubuntu. Get rid of or comment out the lines that say

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

and

```
skip-networking
```

You'll want to restart MySQL then, too, with `sudo service mysql restart` on the command line.

If those don't work, it could be a firewall or port problem, as suggested in another answer.

Comment: Ye I know it's not safe to do but the it's just for testing a program ^^

Comment: `mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO '%'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASS';


Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> flush privileges;

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>` 
I ran this but it's still giving me the same error

Comment: Did you use the password when connecting? Also, I edited my answer... it makes it unnecessarily insecure if you use '%' for the username.

Comment: Did you flush privileges and reset MySQL? First run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` in MySQL, and then run `sudo service mysql restart` on the command line. Another possibility that might help is changing a line in the config file...

Comment: Typically the config file is at `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`. Get rid of or comment out the lines that say `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` and `skip-networking`. You'll want to restart MySQL then, too.

Comment: Ye I had flushed the priveleges already and now restarted mysql but it still is not working... How can I acces the config file (I am kinda new to Ubuntu servers)

Comment: `<your_fav_editor> /etc/mysql/my.conf`. My favorite editor is vim, but if you've never used it before, you will hate it at first. You might need to use `sudoedit`, as those files are typically read-only. `sudoedit` will let you get around that. If that path doesn't work for you, try `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`.

Comment: sure :) I'm also going to add these comments into the answer

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a firewall setting is not allowing access to port 3306?
You can check this from the command prompt to see if it is a network problem or an application issue by connecting to the port with a utility such as netcat (nc).

For example, from the machine running the Navicat/MySQLWorkbench, connecting to the database server with up address 192.168.0.100:

```
user@server1:~> nc -zvn 192.168.0.100 3306
nc: connect to 192.168.0.100 port 3306 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
user@server1:~>
-----
user@server1:~> nc -zvn 192.168.0.100 3306
Connection to 192.168.0.100 3306 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
user@server1:~>
```

To connect by the server's hostname, leave out the -n option:

Comment: `root@vps520749:~# nc -zvn 127.0.0.1 3306

Connection to 127.0.0.1 3306 port [tcp/*] succeeded!

root@vps520749:~#` the connection succeeded

Comment: It appears you're running the navicat and mysql workbench from the same machine running the database? The same machine where you ran that "nc" command?

Comment: The first error message above implies the client did not know the ip address for your hostname. Can you run the "nc" command with the hostname (leave off the n option): `nc -zv vps520749 3396`

Comment: I am running Navicat and MySQL Workbench from another machine on another network than where the server is hosted on

Comment: Then you should run that first nc command from the navicat machine. you need to make sure that you can make the network connection across the network.  Also, you need to make sure the navicate machine knows the ip address of the database server. Put the hostname and ip address into /etc/hosts on the navicat machine.
For example:

    `192.168.0.100       vps520740`

Comment: So I should run ` nc -zvn 54.38.35.5 3306` on the navicat machine? `54.38.35.5` is the IP of my VPS server. Cuz that gives me `connection refused`. Where should I put the ip in? Dont really understand what you mean by `Put the hostname and ip address into /etc/hosts on the navicat machine. `

Comment: Also, please note that any address beginning with 127 is considered a localhost address and not seen across the network. It is used for local programs to connect to services, i.e. the machine talking to itself. Your machine should have another ip address that other machines use to talk to it.

Comment: then your ubuntu machine probably has a firewall running that is not allowing network connections into port 3306 from outside the localhost. Look up how to open a port in Ubuntu's firewall.

Comment: I says the status of the firewall is inactive... So it can't be the problem then right